# why do I get a internal server null pointer exception?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs

This code works completely fine:

```
try {
        sql = "SELECT * from profiles"; 
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 

        while(res.next()) {
            Profiles pProfile = new Profiles(); 
            pProfile.setPersonalnummer(res.getInt(1));
            pProfile.setAnwesenheit(res.getBoolean(2));
            pProfile.setGrundDerAbwesenheit(res.getString(3));
            pProfile.setRolle(res.getString(4));
            pProfile.setWerk(res.getString(5)); 
            pProfile.setMandant(res.getString(6));  
            pProfile.setFileName(res.getString(7));
            allProfiles.add(pProfile);  
        } 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return allProfiles;
```

Somehow this doesn't work:

```
public List<Projects> getAllProjects() {
    try {
        sql = "SELECT * from projects"; 
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 

        while(res.next()) {
            Projects pProject = new Projects(); 
            pProject.setProjektname(res.getString(1));
            pProject.setProjektid(res.getInt(2));
            allProjects.add(pProject);
        } 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return allProjects; 

}
```

I just copy-pasted it, changed the values, but somehow i get a "500 - Internal Server Error" when using the "getAllProjects()" method. The error message says that there is a Null Pointer Exception when executing "allProjects.add(pProject)". 
Maybe somebody can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the entire exception please.

Comment: I don't see the stmp object being created so that is a possibility. You need to show the entire code or at least all relevant code. Also, usually Statement/PrepareStatement/ResultSet are closed after usage but you don't seem to be doingthat as well.

Comment: Where is ```allProjects``` initialized? Cannot see in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add below at top of your method

```
List<Projects> allProjects = new Array<>();
```

Comment: OMG, i feel so dumb right now :(. Forgot to initialize it as an ArryList